# Transaction scope wcf and avoid unwanted Escalation to Distributed Transactions

Tags: wcf, transactions, transactionscope, mstdc

i have problem with escalation distributed transactions in wcf application.

My code looks something like this :

LogRepository

```
    public void AddLog(ImportLogDbo log)
    {
        using (DbManager dbManager = new DbManager("controlServerConnectionString"))
        {
            dbManager.SetSpCommand("dbo.ImportLog_Create",
                                   dbManager.Parameter("@ImportFile", log.ImportFile),
                                   dbManager.Parameter("@ImportError", log.ImportError),
                                   dbManager.Parameter("@ImportHash", log.ImportHash),
                                   dbManager.Parameter("@ImportCompleted", log.ImportCompleted))
             .ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

LogService

```
    public void AddImportLog(string ImportFile, string ImportHash)
    {
        ImportLogDbo importLogDbo = new ImportLogDbo
        {
            ImportCompleted = false,
            ImportFile = ImportFile,
            ImportHash = ImportHash                
        };


        if (_importLogRepository.GetByFileName(ImportFile) == null)
        {
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                _importLogRepository.AddLog(importLogDbo);
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }

    }
```

Project is in .NET 4 and i use Sql Server 2008R2

Code above call my wcf service, which is configured like this

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding" transactionFlow="True" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="5:00:00" openTimeout="5:00:00" receiveTimeout="5:00:00" />          
  </wsHttpBinding>

<endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/AppServer/WsDocumentImportService" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="wsBinding" contract="ComDocs.AppServerServiceLibary.Abstract.IDocumentImportService"/>
```

My problem is in transaction scope, which is ALWAYS promote as distribued.

I'm doing something wrong? (I am bit new in wcf service programming)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

transactionFlow = “true” will propagate the transaction outside the service boundary. Try to set it to false. You you need a more granular transaction scope you could set it using the attribute. for more info have a look at the below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163432.aspx

Comment: Well, if i understand, transactionFlow = "true" is good for transaction initialized in client?
Btw transactionFlow set in false not work, still same problem.

Comment: in general Each Participating Component Should Manage its Own Transactions(if there is not a specific business rule about that) .anyway in this case you don't need to propagate the transaction as the Repository.AddLog doesn't use any.
In your case would be better wrap the repository into a transaction scope and handle the exception at service level

Comment: Yes, this is a bit wrong example. But elsewhere in appliacation i have service with method which calls two-theree repository in one transaction...

Comment: the repository should manage the transaction then and it should be treated as a UnitOfWork.Don't use any transaction at WCF level in this case